# Bluetooth classic connection awareness

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth application that communicates with a peripheral device over a low energy.

This peripheral device also has a classic (HFP and/or A2DP) connection with the iOS device. It happens that the classic connection gets interrupted sometimes.

What I need is to be able to notify the user from in application that the classic connection has been lost.

How can I make my application aware of the classic connection?

What way would you prefer to do this?

Comment: By classic connection do you mean that you are using the `External Accessory` framework? If so you can register for notifications of connection and disconnection.

Comment: no, i'm not using External Accessory framework. I'm only using CoreBluetooth and my app communicates with the device over BLE. But the same device also connects with the iOS device over a classic connection so it can stream audio form iTunes. Can I make my application aware when that (classic) connection is interrupted, and how?

Comment: What do you mean by 'classic connection' bluetooth 2.0?

Comment: Sorry if not enough info. I thought by "streaming" it's understood - HFP and/or A2DP.

Comment: I would try the external accessory framework. I'll post code in an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst CoreBluetooth is used for accessing Bluetooth LE or 4.0 devices you can use the `ExternalAccessory` framework to communicate with other bluetooth devices.

Like so:

```
- (void)registerForNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accessoryDidConnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accessoryDidDisconnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
    [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
} 

- (void)accessoryDidConnect:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Weird thing with ExternalAccessory where this notification is called more than once per accessory...
    if ([[(EAAccessory *)[[(EAAccessoryManager *)notification.object connectedAccessories] lastObject] protocolStrings] count]) {
        // Valid call
        if ([[(EAAccessory *)[notification.userInfo valueForKey:EAAccessoryKey] protocolStrings] containsObject:/*Protocol string for the accessory*/]) {

        }
    }
}

- (void)accessoryDidDisconnect:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[(EAAccessory *)[notification.userInfo valueForKey:EAAccessoryKey] protocolStrings] containsObject:/*Protocol string for the accessory*/]) {
        // Disconnected
    }
}
```

For this to work you have to add the key 'Supported external accessory protocols' to your app's info.plist and list the protocols for the bluetooth devices in the array under that key.

Also note that for distribution on the App Store the bluetooth device has to be registered under the Apple MFi program and you have to be an accepted developer (by the device's manufacturers).

Comment: The device comes from another vendor. Can i presume that this is not my concern?

Comment: If you try to release an App that uses a bluetooth connection that is NOT bluetooth LE, Apple will fail you unless that device is registered in the MFi program and you are an accepted developer. I had this very issue and am now switching to a bluetooth LE device to save myself the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For non-MFI devices, the only way that I have found to get **any** information on connected Bluetooth Classic devices is (indirectly) via the AVAudioSession singleton. 
[AVAudioSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession)

Start by looking at the currentRoute property.